# Transpose multiple columns to one row column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following data:

```
Tag Name          PRD             Start            End 
10PIC700422.PV  10-PSV-700073A  9/9/16 10:44    9/9/16 10:49
10PIC700422.PV  10-PSV-700073B  9/9/16 10:44    9/9/16 10:49
10PIC700422.PV  10-PSV-700073A  9/9/16 10:50    9/9/16 10:51
10PIC700422.PV  10-PSV-700073B  9/9/16 10:50    9/9/16 10:51
11PIC41010.PV   11-PSV-401002A  4/4/16 12:51    4/4/16 13:58
11PIC41010.PV   11-PSV-401002B  4/4/16 12:51    4/4/16 13:58
11PIC41010.PV   11-PSV-401002A  4/4/16 14:04    4/4/16 14:29
11PIC41010.PV   11-PSV-401002B  4/4/16 14:04    4/4/16 14:29
```

I'd like to group by Tag Name and Start DateTime and get distinct Tag Name and Start DateTime but PRD should be transposed to single row with Tag Name as one column, see result I'd like to get:

```
Tag Name PRD                                    Start           End 
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:44    9/9/16 10:49
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:50    9/9/16 10:51
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 12:51    4/4/16 13:58
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 14:04    4/4/16 14:29
```

thanks in advance.
S

Comment: Please edit the second grid there is one more  column than there are column headers.

Comment: There are four rows in table with same tagName.  What rows should the query use to get the two PRDs do you want in the output  for that tagname? Or do you want four columns if the four PRDs were different ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare @t table(Tag_Name varchar(50), PRD varchar(50),Startdt datetime ,Enddt datetime)
insert into @t values
('10PIC700422.PV','10-PSV-700073A','9/9/16 10:44','9/9/16 10:49')
,('10PIC700422.PV','10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44','9/9/16 10:49')
,('10PIC700422.PV','10-PSV-700073A','9/9/16 10:50','9/9/16 10:51')
,('10PIC700422.PV','10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:50','9/9/16 10:51')
,('11PIC41010.PV','11-PSV-401002A','4/4/16 12:51','4/4/16 13:58')
,('11PIC41010.PV','11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 12:51','4/4/16 13:58')
,('11PIC41010.PV','11-PSV-401002A','4/4/16 14:04','4/4/16 14:29')
,('11PIC41010.PV','11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:04','4/4/16 14:29')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY tag_name
            ,startdt ORDER BY startdt
            ) rn
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT tag_name
    ,stuff((
            SELECT '-' + prd
            FROM cte c1
            WHERE c.Tag_Name = c1.Tag_Name
                AND c.Startdt = c1.Startdt
            FOR XML path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') PRD
    ,startdt
    ,enddt
FROM cte c
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I believe John's query slows down because of distinct.